# ˋ[System.Version]::Parse('')´ error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have been trying to create a custom control on Xamarin.Forms.

My solution builds just fine on UWP but with android I always get the same error :

> Impossible to evaluate the expression "[System.Version]::Parse('')". String is either too long or too short.

How Can I solve this ???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using App2;
using App2.UWP;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPannel), typeof(NavigationPannelRenderer))]


namespace App2.UWP
{
    class NavigationPannelRenderer : ViewRenderer<NavigationPannel, NavigationView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPannel> args)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(args);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            NavigationView nav_view = new NavigationView();

            nav_view.MenuItems.Add(new NavigationViewItem
            {
                Content = "My content",
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Folder),
                Tag = "content"
            });

            SetNativeControl(nav_view);
        }
    }
}
}
```

EDIT :
I made another solution and tried to redo everything step by step, my android project compiled just fine at first, but when I Added my UWP custom renderer, and after compiling it on Windows, it started showing the same error

Comment: Please ask the question with a proper information and code snippets.. the information provided is insufficient for anyone to provide you an answer or assist.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I made it step by step again copy/pasting line by line for a third time and this time no error occurs.

I really don't know what happened here so if anyone has any idea i would still gladly accept it.